# print a fit message if a clicked point is found in the circles or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a center coordinates `(x1,y1)` and the radius (`r`) of two circles.

I have another point `A(x2,y2)`, it's the clicked point by the mouse.

I wrote a function that prints a message if the point A is found inside a circle or outside.

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/c4upM/22/

I want to know the next thing:

```
if the clicked pixel is inside the lightblue circle, print 1.
else if the clicked pixel is inside the gray circle, print 2.
else print 3.
```

I build these circles inside the function: `circleInArc`.

in addition, I wrote the functions: `$('#canvas').on('click', function(event) {..}` and `function isPointInsideCircle(center_x, center_y, radius, x, y) {..}` in the javascript area. there are another functions that I wrote in the html area (like `circleInArc`).

please help me,

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To respond to click events in the smaller circles

- When the small blue and gray circles are created, save their x/y coordinates and radius information
- When a mouse event occurs, use your pointInside test to see if the mouse in in either circle.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nrXNh/

The code might look like this:

```
    // When a circle is created send back its x,y & radius
    // We use this info to later check if the mouse is inside this particular circle

    function circleInArc(fillColor,radianAngle){
        var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
        var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,linewidth/2,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
        ctx.fill();
        return({x:x,y:y,radius:linewidth/2});
    }


    // save both circles x,y & radius in a javascript object when calling circleInArc

    var circle1=circleInArc("skyblue",PI*1.5);
    var circle2=circleInArc("lightgray",PI*1.25);


    // listen for mousedown events 
    // I use jquery, but you could substitute pure javascript if you prefer

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


    // when a mousedown occurs, test both circles to see if the mouse is inside
    // then put up an alert with the results of the tests

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // test circle1
      var dx=mouseX-circle1.x;
      var dy=mouseY-circle1.y;
      var rSquared=circle1.radius*circle1.radius;
      if(dx*dx+dy*dy<rSquared){
          alert("Clicked in circle#1");
          return;
      }

      // test circle2
      var dx=mouseX-circle2.x;
      var dy=mouseY-circle2.y;
      var rSquared=circle2.radius*circle2.radius;
      if(dx*dx+dy*dy<rSquared){
          alert("Clicked in circle#2");
          return;
      }

      // otherwise outside circles
      alert("Clicked outside circle#1 and circle#2");

    }
```

Comment: I got it! thank you very much again! what a life saver!